# Pass a simple String Object to a class

Tags: java, string, object

I am trying to send my binary string to checkSequence, but when i display that string object, all I get is blank. Any ideas?

```
public class binaryGame
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
String binaryString = new String(); // creating object I want to send

binaryString.equals(createString());

checkSequence(binaryString);
}

private static String checkSequence(String binaryString)
{
//things
}
```

right now, the program compiles, but the "String binaryString" is empty. I think it is just creating a new binaryString String, but not passing the object. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you initialized your string.
String.equals doesn't affect string object, it only compare them. So you need to do something like this:

```
binaryString = createString();
```